# LiveAgent and locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I'm working on a lightning component that wraps a LiveAgent Chat Button, 
before Locker Service was running it worked as expected.
Now we are having a problem, since once the Locker feature is activated we lost connection with liveAgent service.
Live agent relies on an object attached to the window, we think this object needs to be whitelisted so we can continue accessing it.
Are there plans to give access to liveAgent object ? Or should we review other workarounds? , which at this time we didn't found. 
thanks in advance

Comment: You're probably correct that LockerService needs to whitelist the LiveAgent object on window. I'm not too familiar with how LiveAgent is loaded though. Do you have online instructions you are following? Or example code you could post?